# MongoDB - how to only update field if field does not exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I update a mongo document with the following requirements:

Find a document by email property:

If the document exists:

1. If both retrieved and new document have property A, keep property A (the retrieved one).
2. If retrieved document property A is null or undefined or doesn't exist, update using property A of the new object.

If the document doesn't exist

3. Insert the new document.

The `findOneAndUpdate` seems not to convey the both 3 of the requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to check this for every property or do you already know which is the Property A that you want to update ?

Comment: I have to check every property. Currently, I have to retrieve the old document using `findOne` then merge 2 objects using `Object.assign`  then insert the merged object. That works fine with say a few thousands of records. But I'm working with ~ 5 mill records, it really slows down the process.

Comment: Did you try the below solution ?

Comment: Oh hi, I have been busy working around. I didn't try it yet because my document has over 40 properties, it's not really efficient to do that way. I guess I have to create an if condition for number 1.

Answer (score 12):

My recommendation is to go the following path:

```
db.getCollection('<some-collection>').update(
    { email: 'someguy@email.com' },
    {
        $set: {
            name: "some guy",
            username: someguy,
            tel: '1234'
        }
    },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

Check upsert documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option

Lets go through your requirements now:

**3. If the document doesn't exist, insert the new document.**

Yes, it will insert new document to collection if it doesnt find the document by email. Resulting document will be combination of find condition + $set + autogenerated _id, so it will look something like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...)
    email: 'someguy@email.com'
    name: "some guy",
    username: someguy,
    tel: '1234'
}
```

**2. If retrieved document property A is null or undefined or doesn't exist, update using property A of the new object.**

All properties provided in `$set` will unconditionally be persisted in the database, which also covers your requirement of updating null/undefined values

**3. If both retrieved and new document have property A, keep property A (the retrieved one).**

If both newly provided `A` and database `A` are the same, we dont have a problem.
If `A`s are different, dont you want to store the new `A` value? 
If you are afraid of nulls/undefined values, you can omit them before providing object to $set.
What is the use-case for you not wanting to update database property with newly provided value?
One use-case i can see is that you want to pass `createdAt` in case you are creating new record, but dont want to update that value for existing records.
If thats the case, and you know those properties in advance, you can use `$setOnInsert` update operator. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1

So your update query can look like this:

```
db.getCollection('<some-collection>').update(
    { email: 'someguy@email.com' },
    {
        $set: {
            name: "some guy",
            username: someguy,
            tel: '1234'
        },
        $setOnInsert: {
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }
    },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Well, I got requirement where it should update the new value no matter what the old value is, the upsert parameter conveys this requirement. This is the reverse one, however.

Comment: $setOnInsert is what I was looking for! glad i don't need to use mongoose for this

Answer (score 3):

You need not retrieve the document for updating the property A. You can use the `update` API of mongo to do so. Please find the psuedo code below:

```
db.<collection>.update({
    "$or": [
        { "PropertyA": { "$exists": false } }, 
        { "PropertyA": null }
    ]
}, {$set: {"PropertyA": "NewValue"}});
```

The above code is for one property, but I think you can figure out how to scale it up.

Hope this helps !!